# Utilização das funções bind, unbind, off e on

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de saber se é possível, e se for como é feito para utilizar as funções bind, unbind, on e off juntas?

Comment: Considere ser mais especifico. O que você gostaria de saber se é possível? Para saber como faz pra utilizar as funções, utilize a documentação do jQuery que é muito bem documentada, com exemplos e etc.

Comment: @TiagoSilva o bind e o on são basicamente iguais. A diferênça está descrita na pergunta que sugeri como duplicada. O off e o unbind são semelhantes, nomes diferentes em gerações/versões diferentes de jQuery.